# Google Play Console - App reviews got disappeared

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Till 30th September i had 103 reviews for my app. On 1st October all my reviews are disappeared. Now i have only 8 reviews ?

What's the real problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal case it can take 1–2 months for an average app to get 100 real reviews. At the same time anybody can purchase 100 reviews for $25 or $30 in one day. Google assuming it as fake reviews. That's why your reviews got deleted.